# Rotational Dynamics Problem Involving Multiple Rods

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

> In the figure shown, the rod $OA$ of length $1 \ \rm m$ is rotating
> about the fixed point $O$ and the rod $AB$ of length $1\ \rm m$ is
> rotating about $A$, in a vertical plane. At a certain moment, when
> $OA$ is making an angle  $60^\circ$ with the horizontal, the rod $AB$
> is horizontal. At the same moment angular speed and angular
> acceleration of $OA$ and $AB$ are $2 \ \rm rad/s$, $2\sqrt 3 \rm \
>  rad/s^2$ and $1 \ \rm rad/s$, $3\sqrt3 \rm \ rad/s^2$ respectively.
> Calculate the acceleration of point $B$ in $\rm m/s^2$  at that
> moment.

[image]

**My approach:**

I assumed the acceleration
of centre of mass of rod AB to have x and y components and via constraints at point A(using angular acceleration of rod OA as it is hinged to the ground and equating it to acceleration due to rod AB caused by its x,y acceleration and angular acceleration and also ensuring that there are no components of acceleration perpendicular to acceleration caused by hinge(O) at A.). The net acceleration at B can by found by using x and y components of acceleration of rod Ab, its angular acceleration and centripetal acceleration. However I am not getting the answer. Am i going conceptually wrong somewhere?. It would be great if someone could help me out with this one

Comment: Do not expect numeric answers below (to adhere with homework policy), so you might as well remove the quantities and only indicate what is known and what is unknown.

Comment: @John Alexiou Not sure if this is more of a meta post, but I would leave the values because these questions often come from popular textbooks, and students may search them by typing the exact phrasing w/ values, which increases their likelihood of finding this SE question.

Comment: The rod center of mass is unimportant here. The CM is important only when applying the equations of motion ($F=ma$ etc), but the problem above is purely kinematics. It is the study of motion in relation to the degrees of freedom of the system. It is finding _all possible_ motions that can arise from a system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard kinematics problem.

The steps to solve these is to first designate the degrees of freedom of the system. Use the two orientation angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ is conventionally what is used for pin joints.

[image: fig1]

Then track the points of interest (since dynamics are not involved, each center of mass isn't important here) in terms of position, velocity and acceleration. This is done by taking the time derivative using the chain rule.

$$ \begin{aligned} \vec{\rm pos}_A &=  \pmatrix{ \ell \cos \theta_1 \\ \ell \sin \theta_1} & \vec{\rm pos}_B & = \vec{\rm pos}_A + \pmatrix{ \ell \cos \theta_2 \\ \ell \sin \theta_2 } \end{aligned} $$

$$ \begin{aligned} \vec{\rm vel}_A &=  \pmatrix{ \ell \omega_1 \sin \theta_1 \\ -\ell \omega_1 \cos \theta_1} & \vec{\rm vel}_B & = \vec{\rm vel}_A + \pmatrix{ \ell \omega_2 \sin \theta_2 \\- \ell \omega_2 \cos \theta_2 } \end{aligned} $$

where $\dot{\theta}_1 = -\omega_1$ and $\dot{\theta}_2 = -\omega_2$ from the rotational sense of the sketch above.

and one more time

$$ \begin{aligned} \vec{\rm acc}_A &= \pmatrix{ \ell \alpha_1 \sin \theta_1 - \ell \omega^2 \cos \theta_1 \\ -\ell \alpha_1 \cos \theta_1 - \ell \omega_1^2 \sin \theta_1} & \vec{\rm acc}_B & =\vec{acc}_A + \pmatrix{ \ell \alpha_2 \sin \theta_2 - \ell \omega_2^2 \cos \theta_2 \\ -\ell \alpha_2 \cos \theta_2 - \ell \omega_2^2 \sin \theta_2  } \end{aligned} $$

where $\dot{\omega}_1 = \alpha_1$ and $\dot{\omega}_2 = \alpha_2$.

Now you have symbolic expressions of the acceleration of each point, which you use in the situation you want to examine.

---

You could also solve the above using the velocity and acceleration transformation equations

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \vec{\rm vel}_A & = \vec{\omega}_1 \times \vec{\rm pos}_1 \\
  \vec{\rm vel}_B & = \vec{\rm vel}_A + \vec{\omega}_2 \times ( \vec{\rm pos}_2 - \vec{\rm pos}_1 ) \\
  \vec{\rm acc}_A & = \vec{\alpha}_1 \times \vec{\rm pos}_1 + \vec{\omega}_1 \times \vec{\rm vel}_1 \\
  \vec{\rm acc}_B & = \vec{\rm acc}_A + \vec{\alpha}_2 \times( \vec{\rm pos}_2 - \vec{\rm pos}_1) + \vec{\omega}_2 \times ( \vec{\rm vel}_2 - \vec{\rm vel}_1) \\ 
\end{aligned}$$

but I think the above is far more complex and tedious compared to the direct differentiation method presented above at first.

Comment: yes i understood both methods and will keep this approach in mind but I really want to know what is wrong in my approach.

Comment: @Aasneh I cannot comment on the specifics on your approach since you haven't posted any details. From the wording, it seems like you took the last vector equation above transforming the acceleration from **A** to the center of mass, and then from the center of mass to **B**. This is identical to performing a single step from **A** to **B** as shown below.